# Insertion of nodes in a linked list

Tags: multithreading, linked-list

There are two running threads each with a node and I need to insert them into a list of  singly linked list .

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do it is to not lock the list but instead prepare a list-node and then publish it with compare-and-swap. This 'publish' semantic means that if the CAS failed you then first update the list-node with the new 'next'-pointer and then retry the CAS; you do this until the CAS succeeded.

Comment: Does that apply to a very long list as well ?

Comment: You have 2 costs: one for searching the insertion-position and one for locking. Using CAS instead of locking the list reduces the locking-cost to almost 0. But the searching-cost is almost unchanged; you would need a different datastructure to get faster sorted-insertion.

Comment: Thanks, I am just searching how does locking the list mechanism works

Comment: Oh ok, so you just want basic locking: how you can do that depends on the programming language and operating system, so please tell us.

Comment: In C and Linux . I was thinking if it can be done in minimum waiting time by Mutual exclusion using coarse grained solution to implement a lock , tie breaker algorithm or bakery algorithm . I am not sure about it.